# How to filter a table with 2 where clauses in breeze js

Tags: metadata, breeze

I am trying to get all records that meet my conditions in my table.
Here is my Breeze function:

```
 function getAll(page, size) {
        var take = size || 40;
        var skip = page ? (page - 1) * size : 0;
        var predicate = Predicate.create('issueStatusId', '==', 1,
            'or', 'issueStatusId', '==' , 2);


        return EntityQuery.from('Issues')
            .where(predicate)
            .orderBy(orderBy)
            .take(take)
            .skip(skip)
            .expand('Status,  Category', 'Notes')
            .toType(entityName)
           .using(this.manager)
            .execute()
            .to$q(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var datarecieved = data.results;

            return datarecieved;

        }
    }
```

As you can see above , i am trying to get all the records that have either issueStatusId of  1or IssueStatusId of 2. That function at the moment only returns records with the issueStatusId of 1.  What is the best way to write 2 where clauses in breese js? or is this not possible at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea with the predicate, but the syntax was a little off.  It should be:

```
var predicate = Predicate.create('issueStatusId', '==', 1)
    .or('issueStatusId', '==' , 2);
```